# How to change the hour and minutes of a DateTime variable

Tags: c#, .net

How can I change the hour and minutes of a variable of type `DateTime`?

What I have tried:

```
alarme[count] = DateTime.Now;
alarme[count].Hour = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
alarme[count].Minute = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
```

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0200  Property or indexer 'DateTime.Hour' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: what do you want to do in each case?

Comment: DateTime is immutable. The errors are essentially telling you that.

Comment: Radiobutton1: Add time to the current time.
Radiobutton2: set the time.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: you have to read the doc for DateTime class. All the answers are there https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read the values of `Hour` etc. If you want to set those properties, you need to use `AddHours` as you do or override the `DateTime` with a new `DateTime`.

You can do this:

```
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now
            alarme[count] = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), now.Second);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

```
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                {
                    alarme[count] = DateTime.Now.Date + new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), 0);
                }
```